# I want to check message.content while message.content != number

Tags: discord.js

how to check the message .content of new messages

```json
client.on("interactionCreate", interaction => {

  if(interaction.isCommand()){
    if(interaction.commandName == "bingo"){
      let min = interaction.options.getInteger("min");
      let max = interaction.options.getInteger("max");
      max -min;
      let number = Math.floor(Math.random()*max)
      let founded = false

      let first_embed = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle("Bingo")
        .setDescription(`the aim of the game is find Number between ${Discord.bold(min)} and ${Discord.bold(max)}`)
        .setFooter({text:interaction.guild.name,iconURL:interaction.guild.iconURL()})
      interaction.reply({embeds:[first_embed]});

      while(!founded){
        interaction.channel
      }
      
    }
```

i try to check message.content of new messages

Comment: What are you trying to do here? the messages are not clear. Also, please come back after an attempt is made.

Comment: because i need to know how to check message.content of messages while the message . content != number

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure on what you are trying to do, but if you want to check if a string is a number, you can use [Number.isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN)

for example:

```
if (Number.isNaN(string)) {
  // string IS NOT a number
} else {
  // string IS a number
}
```